# How to make a always on placeholder/hint for Jetpack Compose TextField?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-material3

M3 `TextField` has a `placeholder` parameter where it shows a text when it's focused and empty. But I want to show a placeholder or a hint always as the user is typing. Something similar to search suggestions but more like Github Copilot suggestions which suggest text as you type.

[image: current effort]

Visually I achieved what I want but currently, when the cursor is moved it's not moving logically I suspect `OffsetMapping` is responsible for that but I can't fix it. The problem is when you try to move the cursor it moves but sometimes jumps to the end of the green text instead of moving smoothly.

```kotlin
class MyMaskTransformation(
    private val suggestion: String
) : VisualTransformation {

    private var suffix: String = ""

    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        suffix = if (suggestion.length > text.length)
            suggestion.takeLast(suggestion.length - text.length)
        else ""
        return TransformedText(
            offsetMapping = offsetMapping,
            text = buildAnnotatedString {
                withStyle(SpanStyle(Color.Unspecified)) {
                    append(text)
                }
                withStyle(SpanStyle(Color.Gray)) {
                    append(suffix)
                }
            }
        )
    }

    private val offsetMapping = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset < suggestion.length || suggestion.isEmpty()) return offset
            return suggestion.length - suffix.length
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            offset.toString().log()
            if (offset == 0) return 0
            if (suggestion.length - suffix.length in 1 until offset)
                return suggestion.length - suffix.length
            return offset
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To add an extra view to a text field, you can use a `BasicTextField` with one of the standard decoration boxes.

For example, instead of `OutlinedTextField` you can use `TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox`, and in `innerTextField` you can decorate the text field according to your requirements:

```
var value by remember {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
val suggestion = "Suggestion"
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
val colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
val textStyle = TextStyle.Default
BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { value = it },
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    textStyle = textStyle,
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
        TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
            value = value,
            innerTextField = {
                Box {
                    Text(suggestion, style = textStyle.copy(color = Color.Gray))
                    innerTextField()
                }
            },
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            label = { Text("chat") },
            trailingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Send, null) },
            colors = colors,
            enabled = true,
            singleLine = true,
            visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
            border = {
                TextFieldDefaults.BorderBox(
                    enabled = true,
                    isError = false,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    colors = colors,
                )
            }
        )
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of Material3 are you using? I'm using `1.1.0-beta01` and its `OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox` has no border parameter.

Comment: @YaMiN  I didn't notice that you are using the M3, but you should be able to use the same principle there. Let me know if you think I should updated my code to M3.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by placing another text under input, it works also with spaces and makes placeholder mask under actual input invisible.

Compose version: 1.5.4,
Compose Material: 1.5.4,
Compose Material3: 1.1.2

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun MaskableInputText(
    value: String,
    mask: String
) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    val colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors()
    val textStyle = TextStyle.Default
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(value)) }

    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { value = it },
        textStyle = textStyle,
        visualTransformation = { value.applyMask(mask) },
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
                value = value.text,
                innerTextField = {
                    Box {
                        Text(
                            text = value.transformMask(mask),
                            color = Color.Gray
                        )
                        innerTextField()
                    }
                },
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                label = { Text("chat") },
                trailingIcon = { Icon(Icons.Default.Send, null) },
                colors = colors,
                enabled = true,
                singleLine = true,
                visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                border = {
                    TextFieldDefaults.BorderBox(
                        enabled = true,
                        isError = false,
                        interactionSource = interactionSource,
                        colors = colors,
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    )
}

private fun TextFieldValue.applyMask(mask: String): TransformedText {
    val spacePositions = mask.mapIndexedNotNull { position, char -> position.takeIf { char == ' ' } }

    val maskedInput = StringBuilder(this.text).apply {
        spacePositions.forEach { position -> if (position <= length) insert(position, " ") }
    }.toString()

    return TransformedText(
        text = AnnotatedString(maskedInput),
        offsetMapping = SpacingOffsetTranslator(spacePositions)
    )
}

fun TextFieldValue.transformMask(mask: String): AnnotatedString {
    val positions = mask.mapIndexedNotNull { position, char -> position.takeIf { char == ' ' } }

    val maskedInput = StringBuilder(text).apply {
        positions.forEach { position -> if (position <= length) insert(position, " ") }
    }.toString()

    val visibleMaskText = mask.substring(maskedInput.length, mask.length)

    return buildAnnotatedString {
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(color = Color.Transparent)) { append(maskedInput) }
        append(visibleMaskText)
    }
}

private class SpacingOffsetTranslator(private val spacePositions: List<Int>) : OffsetMapping {
    override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
        spacePositions.forEachIndexed { index, position -> if (offset <= position) return offset + index }
        return offset + spacePositions.size
    }

    override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
        spacePositions.forEachIndexed { index, position -> if (offset <= position) return offset - index }
        return offset - spacePositions.size
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you specify which version of Compose you are using? I'm currently using Compose Compiler version `1.5.7` and for other Compose libs I'm using `1.5.4` and I'm using Material3 `1.1.2`  It seems `TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox` is both Deprecated and Experimental at the same time which is very typical of Android development. BTW there's no `border` parameter for that in a version I'm using and `TextFieldDefaults.BorderBox` doesn't even exist at all. Anyway, what's `TGInputSpacingVisualTransformation`?

Comment: @YaMiN Ihave edied an answer with SpacingVisualTransformations and versions that I have used, I think TextFieldDefaults.BorderBox comes from Material not Material3. But anyway this way it should work on all kinda decoration boxes